# Design Static Classes w/ Shared Functionality through Inheritance

Tags: c#, database

I have a number of static repository classes that hold and retrieve data objects. I want to provide some common functionality to them, so I have them inherit from an abstract class.

This doesn't work, since static classes are not allowed to inherit. I trust in the .NET design, so I will accept that this is for good reason.

So this leads me to believe I have some fundamental design issues here.

My question is how do I design my code to achieve the result I'm looking for? Or, is it just a matter of having to replicate the methods across all my classes. Perhaps a singleton?

**Static Repo:**

```
public static class CreditMemos : InvoiceRepository<CreditMemo>
{
    public static List<CreditMemo> GetByDocumentNumber(string documentNumber)
    {
        return CheckCache(
            ConvertReaderToCreditMemos(
                Invoices.GetByDocumentNumber<CreditMemo>(documentNumber)));
    }
}
```

**Desired Base:**

```
abstract class InvoiceRepository<t>
    where t: DataObjects.Invoice
{
    static List<t> invoiceCache = new List<t>();

    static protected List<t> CheckCache(List<t> results)
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
            if (!invoiceCache.Any(p => p.ID == result.ID))
                invoiceCache.Add(result);
        return invoiceCache.Where(p => results.Any(a => a.ID == p.ID)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could consider using dependency injection which could allow you to share a single instance of a non-static repository more easily.

Comment: And this is why Singletons exist.

Comment: If you care at all about unit testing, use dependency injection of an interface. It'll make your life much easier down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just drop the `static` from your inheriting classes, and make them work similarly by hiding the constructor:

```
public sealed class CreditMemos : InvoiceRepository<CreditMemo>
{
    private CreditMemos() { }
    ...
```

Or you can make `InvoiceRepository<t>` its own `static class`, and instead of inheriting, you just use the methods in your other `static class`es. (by the way, the convention is to capitalize the first letter in all type names, including generic types, so `T`, not `t`)

```
public static class CreditMemos
{
    public static List<CreditMemo> GetByDocumentNumber(string documentNumber)
    {
        return InvoiceRepository<CreditMemo>.CheckCache(new List<CreditMemo>());
    }
}
public static class InvoiceRepository<T>
    where T: DataObjects.Invoice
{
    static List<T> invoiceCache = new List<T>();

    static internal List<T> CheckCache(List<T> results)
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
            if (!invoiceCache.Any(p => p.ID == result.ID))
                invoiceCache.Add(result);
        return invoiceCache.Where(p => results.Any(a => a.ID == p.ID)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just refactored to a singleton, I hadn't even considered hiding the constructor. That may work just fine... there is no state information stored in the repo itself. Also - thanks for the pointer on T. I was thinking of it in terms of a parameter.