# Is there an alternative to Inheritable static generic classes in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static

I would like to have a series of static classes which each contain a dictionary and perform two methods on the dictionary.  The methods are identical in all versions of the class except for an argument type in one method and return type in another method.

Ideally, I'd like to put the behavior (the methods) in a "base" generic static class, then create several typed *static* descendants which each contain their own static dictionary.  Obviously, I can't do this because one static class cannot inherit from another static class.

I'm wondering if there is any alternative way to accomplish my goal.  I know I could make this work with non-static classes, but it seems to me this is more appropriately a static task.

Here is a sketch of what I want:

```
public static class BaseClass<T>
{
  private static Dictionary<string, T> PrivateDict {get; set;}

  private static String ToString(T argument)
  {
     return Somestring;
  }

  private static T FromString(string argument)
  {
     return Some-T-thing;
  }
}

// This static class supplies the static dictionary but gets the static methods of BaseClass.
// Other static classes might exit that use, for instance, Dictionary<string, XElement>
public static class GenderClass : BaseClass<int>
{
  private static Dictionary<string, int> PrivateDict = new Dictionary<string, int>
  {
      {"Male", 1},
      {"Boy", 1},
      {"M", 1},
      {"Female", 2},
      {"Girl", 2},
      {"F", 2}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not have a *non* static class with a static member for the base class and a static member for the child?

Comment: I asked a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895395/design-static-classes-w-shared-functionality-through-inheritance that might be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the type as the path to "inheritance". I say that in quotes because it is really just a bypass but it should still work in a similar way you want.

I tested this in LinqPad and it produced the correct results with no exceptions thrown. Note that the fields were made public for testing purposes.

First, set up an interface that you can use to pass dictionaries around with.

```
public interface IPublicDictionary<T>
{
 Dictionary<string, T> PublicDictionary { get; }
}
```

Next, set up your class (non static) which will implement the interface and expose a unique dictionary

```
public class GenderClass : IPublicDictionary<int>
{
 public static Dictionary<string, int> PublicDict = new Dictionary<string, int>
 {
  {"Male", 1},
  {"Boy", 1},
  {"M", 1},
  {"Female", 2},
  {"Girl", 2},
  {"F", 2}
 };

 public Dictionary<string, int> PublicDictionary
 {
  get { return PublicDict; }
 }
}
```

Now the class is ready to be used in the static base class which has turned into the main place of work.

```
public static class BaseClass
{
 public static String ToString<F,T>(F argument) where T : IPublicDictionary<F>, new()
 {
  IPublicDictionary<F> t = new T();
  return t.PublicDictionary.First(d => Comparer<F>.Equals((F)d.Value, argument)).Key;
 }

 public static F FromString<T,F>(string argument) where T : IPublicDictionary<F>, new()
  {
   IPublicDictionary<F> t = new T();
   return t.PublicDictionary[argument];
  }
}
```

Once this is setup, all that is left is to simply call the base class. Here are the two samples I tried.

```
var s = BaseClass.FromString<GenderClass,int>("F");
Console.WriteLine(s);
var t = BaseClass.ToString<int,GenderClass>(2);
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Which outputs

```
2
Female
```

Comment: In this solution, it looks like I'm instantiating an instance of GenderClass every time I want to convert a string to gender, or vice-versa.  This code will be used in ETL work with potentially hundreds of thousands of calls, so I'm worried about the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The decision about whether something should be static or not has to do with the way you're going to use that. If you have to have something static there, I'd personally do it like this:

- have an interface for logic. Then make as many classes implementing it as necessary, each specializing the logic. If there is any shared logic, maybe make a non static, base abstract class instead, again with as many children as necessary.
- In a given method of your static class, choose which logic-implementing class you wish to use based on the parameters you got. Then instantiate an object of the chosen class, call the relevant method, and return its result.

I.e.: something like this:

```
public interface foo
{
    string ToString(someBase input);
    someBase FromString(string input);
}

public static class Bar
{
    public static string ToString(someBase input)
    {
        if (input.GetType() == typeof(Duck))
        {
            foo duckie = new DuckHandler();
            return duckie.ToString(input);
        }
        else if (input.GetType() == typeof(DeadParrot)) { /* ..snip.. */ }
    }

    public static someBase FromString(string input, type Type) {
        if (type == typeof(Duckie))
        {
            foo duckie = new DuckHandler(input);
            return duckie;
        }
        else if (type == typeof(OKLumberjack)) { /* ..snip.. */ }
    }
}
```

You can see where this goes.